# is Unique Key Constraint creating an index behind the scenes for the table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that has `n` number of columns: amongst them `id` (primary key), `name` and `org_id`. Names must be unique within org_id, so I am slapping unique key constraint on that pair.

Now, in the application code, I have checks, where I verify if name for my entity is unique across organization.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE name=? and org_id=?
```

I have `org_id` as a foreign key to `Organizations` table.

In order to speed up queries as I mentioned above, should I introduce an index against the `name` column? Or, maybe, there is no need, and the Unique Key index (`org_id-name`) will kick in and make my queries fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNIQUE constraint is already backed by an index. I assume it takes the form:

```
constraint uq_1 unique (org_id, name)
```

Your query should be fast already when using "equality searches", like the one you show, using the predicate:

```
WHERE name = ? and org_id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense!